# Uncaught TypeError: Object is not a function in fetch API result

Tags: reactjs, api

I need to access products  that is inside a result from an API fetch. I tried multiple ways but is says or that map is undefined or something else.

Here's the imagem of the json response:

[image]
Here is action:

```
function getProducts(products) {
return request
    .get(process.env.API_URL + 'url')
    .send({
        products: products,
    })
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .then((data) => console.log(data));}
```

Here is React component

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getProducts(this.state.products).end((err, data) => {
      if (!err) {
        this.setState({
          products: data.body[0].products,

        });
      }
    });
  }
```

and my map function is inside render:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.products.map((p, index) => (
```

Thanks for any advice!

**Update**

This is response for console.log(this.state.products)

[image]

Comment: Where is your map function?

Comment: inside render:

return (
      <div>
        {this.state.products.map((p, index) =>

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(this.state.products)`?

Comment: @Nat can you share response json?

Comment: Use `data.body.products` in setState, `data.body` is not an array so `data.body[0]` will return undefined.

Comment: @AfiaUdofia I update respnse of this console log

Comment: @hazardous I changed it, but response of console.log(this.state.products) is same as above

Comment: `Console.log(data)` in the `if (!err) { ... }` in `componentDidMount()`

Comment: @AfiaUdofia also undefined update functions like below, but still products are undefined.
but in console.log from action there is array in this directory data.body.products

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message, what I'd done wrong is destructured an import that didn't need destructuring.

```
import { fetch } from "isomorphic-unfetch";
```

Should have been

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";
```

Not sure if this solves your issue, but thought it was worth putting it down incase it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is not returned from your getProducts function. You are just console logging it. Return `data` in your `.then` callback function.

```
function getProducts(products) {
    return request
        .get(process.env.API_URL + 'url')
        .send({
            products: products,
        })
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
    });  
}
```

and then modify `componentDidMount` function to

```
  componentDidMount() {
    getProducts(this.state.products).end((err, data) => {
      if (!err) {
        this.setState({
          products: data.body.products,

        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: ty for your answer, but unfortunately error is still there. 
It seems all the time like products are undefined.
but in action file when i 
console.log(data.body.products) 
I got this array

Comment: Create a simple demo on github and share the link?

Comment: Okey,  I'll try to make it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for that error was to change a bit getProducts function, remove all .then:

```
    function getProducts(products) {
    return request
        .get(process.env.API_URL + 'url')
        .send({
            products: products,
        })
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    });  
}
```